# Is there a way to use javascript/jquery to search a group of li tags and narrow the search down

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I have been looking all over the web for ideas on how to do this. I have a [DrillDown menu](http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-drill-down-menu-plugin/getting-started/) that at some points goes six levels deep (not my choice this is what the customer wants) I have created an xml document that holds all of these items there are a total of 106 different options that a user can select just in the side menu alone (again its what the customer wants). I want to create a search box that would allow me to type in the name of one of the selections and the list would shrink to only show the options with the word(s) that the user inputs.

My question Is there a plugin that would allow this behavior?

If not How do you search a group of li elements for text?

Comment: This will all depend on the Final HTML structure and which elements you want to search through (For example do you want to search through the HTML value or values inside the li tags).

Comment: Only value's in the li tags. The rest of the pages are basically reports that the user would like to view. The search field is literally only used for the navigation to make it easier to navigate

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To code it yourself would be fairly straightforward, the jQuery below takes a string from the input #inputString and will iterate through the list items "ul li" and show/hide depending if they match the input string.

You can modify the "ul li" selector to contain other lists if needed

```
jQuery("#inputString").keyup(function () {
    var filter = jQuery(this).val();
    jQuery("ul li").each(function () {
        if (jQuery(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
            jQuery(this).hide();
        } else {
            jQuery(this).show()
        }
    });
});
```

I expect there are many plugins that do the same thing, give it a google!

Comment: I suspect at this point I was googling the wrong things I will refine my search based on the answers

Comment: I would give it a go with one of these answers, its only a few lines of code

Comment: very great answer

Answer (score 7):

You can try to filter by `contains` selector:

```
var matches = $( 'ul#myMenu' ).find( 'li:contains(search string) ' );
$( 'li', 'ul#myMenu' ).not( matches ).slideUp();
matches.slideDown();
```

See example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59FbY/)

Answer (score 2):

> How do you search a group of li elements for text?

```
var filteredLIS = $("li:contains('" + yourQuery + "')");
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Start here: Search Service area via jQuery
  window.filter = function(element)
  {
    var value = $(element).val().toUpperCase();
    $(".left_message > li").each(function() 
    {
      if ($(this).text().toUpperCase().search(value) > -1){
        $(this).show();
      }
      else {
        $(this).hide();
      }
    });
  }
});
</script>

<input type="text"  placeholder="Enter text to search" onkeyup="filter(this);">

<ul role="tablist" class="left_message">
    <li><a href="#"><span>Anupk Kumar</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Pradeep Kumar</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Zahid Gani</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Amitabh</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Chandan Gupta</span></a></li> 
</ul>



Result : Search Zahid , they return following output

<ul role="tablist" class="left_message">`enter code here`
    <li><a href="#"><span>Zahid Gani</span></a></li>    
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the drilldown sample here:

```
http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-drill-down-menu-plugin/getting-started/
```

This is my suggestion:

```
$('#drilldown').find("a:contains('Product')");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this concept:

```
$('.search').keyup(function(){
    if( $(this).val().length > 0 ){
        var foundin = $('#drilldown').find('li a:contains("'+$(this).val()+'")');
    }
});
```